# Jquery Toggle on click of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, toggle

I am trying to understand how the jquery toggle works. I want to toggle to next anchor with class `plr-anchor` on click of image with class `go_down`. The data is populated using maps.

Jquery code:

```
$('.go_down').on('click',function(e){
    #('.plr-anchor').next('.plr-anchor').toggle()});
}
```

Code snippet:

```
{data.map(function(categ) {
return <div>
<a className="plr-anchor" id={categ.short_name}></a>
<img src="/static/img/icon_up.png" className="go_down"/>
</div>}.bind(this)}
```

There seems to be a problem with the syntax on the Jquery call function. I am newbie with Jquery, any help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have provided a hash `#('.plr-anchor').next('.plr-anchor').toggle()});` in this. Try `$('.plr-anchor').next('.plr-anchor').toggle()});`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `#` instead of `$` inside click handler. Also you need to find exact `plr-anchor` which is before the clicked image. Right now you are toggling all `plr-anchor`.

For dynamic elements, use `$(document).on(event, selector, function(){});` for binding click handlers. See below code

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.go_down',function(e){
     $(this).prev('.plr-anchor').toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your jQuery code has a "#" instead of a "$". By the way, React and jQuery don't always go together. The whole purpose of React is to use virtual dom and let React take care of dom updates. While jQuery is mostly about direct dom manipulation. What you are trying here will interfere with React because it won't expect the dom to change without the v-dom changing.

Ideally, you should be using event handlers and state in your component to toggle visibility.

Comment: Thank you , i updated the code to use the event handlers.